# SQL/Bigquery: Pivot combinations of rows into columns, keeping all pairs

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, pivot, case

Say I have a table like:

```
| id |  brand |   fuel | mpg |
|:--:|:------:|:------:|:---:|
| 1  | ford   | diesel | 14  |
| 1  | ford   | gas    | 20  |
| 1  | toyota | diesel | 30  |
| 1  | toyota | gas    | 35  |
```

and I wish to pivot the columns such that the result is like:

```
| id |  ford  | toyota | toyota_mpg | ford_mpg |
|:--:|:------:|--------|:----------:|:--------:|
| 1  | diesel | diesel | 30         | 14       |
| 1  | gas    | gas    | 35         | 20       |
| 1  | diesel | gas    | 35         | 14       |
| 1  | gas    | diesel | 30         | 20       |
```

So far, I have

```
SELECT id,
         MAX(CASE WHEN end_use = 'ford' THEN fuel ELSE NULL END) ford,
         SUM(CASE WHEN end_use = 'ford' THEN mpg ELSE NULL END) ford_mpg,

         MAX(CASE WHEN end_use = 'toyota' THEN fuel ELSE NULL END) toyota,
         SUM(CASE WHEN end_use = 'toyota' THEN mpg ELSE NULL END) toyota_mpg,
       FROM table GROUP BY id, fuel
```

which results below, giving me the correct result for when the fuels align:

```
| id |  ford  | toyota | toyota_mpg | ford_mpg |
|:--:|:------:|--------|:----------:|:--------:|
| 1  | diesel | diesel | 30         | 14       |
| 1  | gas    | gas    | 35         | 20       |
```

But I am not able to get the combinations of fuels (where they mismatch).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below

```
select id, 
  t1.fuel ford, 
  t2.fuel toyota, 
  t1.mpg ford_mpg, 
  t2.mpg toyota_mpg
from data t1
join data t2
using (id)
where t1.brand < t2.brand
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can explore the [pivot operator](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#pivot_operator) from the big query. Though I am not sure about your use-case to find out sum/avg/max/min on id level!

```
WITH
  result AS (
  SELECT
    1 AS id,
    'ford' AS brand,
    'diesel' AS fuel,
    14 AS mpg
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    1 AS id,
    'ford' AS brand,
    'gas' AS fuel,
    20 AS mpg
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    1 AS id,
    'toyota' AS brand,
    'diesel' AS fuel,
    30 AS mpg
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    1 AS id,
    'toyota' AS brand,
    'gas' AS fuel,
    35 AS mpg ),
  pivot_result AS (
  SELECT
    id,
    ford,
    toyota,
    mpg_ford,
    mpg_toyota
  FROM (
    SELECT
      *
    FROM (
      SELECT
        id,
        fuel,
        brand brand_,
        brand,
        mpg
      FROM
        result ) PIVOT ( AVG(mpg) mpg FOR brand IN ('ford',
          'toyota')) ) PIVOT (MAX(fuel) FOR brand_ IN ('ford',
        'toyota')) )
SELECT
  f.id,
  f.ford,
  t.toyota,
  t.mpg_toyota,
  f.mpg_ford
FROM
  pivot_result f
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT
    id,
    toyota,
    mpg_toyota
  FROM
    pivot_result) t
ON
  t.id = f.id
WHERE
  (f.ford IS NOT NULL
    AND f.mpg_ford IS NOT NULL
    AND t.toyota IS NOT NULL
    AND t.mpg_toyota IS NOT NULL)
GROUP BY
  1,
  2,
  3,
  4,
  5
```